# How to work with postgresql JSON where keys are arbitrary?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a JSON field c1 in a table t1 which is of form

```
{
 "11111" : { "STATUS" : "1"},
 "22222" : { "STATUS" : "0"},
 "33333" : { "STATUS" : "0"}
}
```

I want find those row of t1 in which any keys status is 1, I have tried below command

```
with r1 as(select t1.*, json_object_keys(c1) as keys from t1) select * from r1 where r1.c1->keys->>'STATUS' = '1';
```

but it is not giving me any row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from t1
where exists (
    select 1
    from json_each(c1)
    where value ->> 'STATUS' = '1'
)
```